# Is it possible to construct a multiplicative group from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ if $n$ is not a prime number?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, prime-numbers, group-theory

With $n$ being a prime number I know we can generate groups over multiplication. Is it possible the other way around ($n$ not being a prime)?

Comment: multiplicative group

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**. The subset of $\Bbb Z_n$ of integers that are relatively prime to $n$ (otherwise said: the set of $x$ in $\Bbb Z_n$ with $\gcd(n,x)=1$ ) form a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) under the multiplicative law of $\Bbb Z_n$ (multiplication modulo $n$ ).

That [finite group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_group) is noted $(\Bbb Z_n^*,*)$ or just $\Bbb Z_n^*$, or $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$. It has $\varphi(n)$ elements, where $\varphi$ is the [Euler totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

That group is [cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) (otherwise said: generated by a single element) iff $n$ is in one of three forms: $4$, $p^k$, $2p^k$ (for $p$ an odd prime and $k\in\Bbb N$, including $k=0$); that is for $n$ in [A033948](https://oeis.org/A033948).

<sub>Thanks to Poncho for a [useful comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/168538).</sub>

Comment: Further information: that group is generally represented as the integers between 1 and $n$ that are relatively prime to $n$, and that group has $\phi(n)$ elements.  That group is cyclic (generated by a single element) iff $n$ is in one of three forms: $4, p^k, 2p^k$ (for $p$ an odd prime)

Comment: "iff $n$ is in one of three forms: $4,p^k,2p^k$ (for p an odd prime and $k \in \mathbb{N}$)" this characterization uses a (common but far from universal) definition of $\mathbb{N}$ that includes $0$. Otherwise $1,2$ need to be added.

Comment: @Maeher: I removed that ambiguity. But that's the first time I heard of $0$ not being in $\Bbb N$ when there is the double oblique bar in the **N**. Any reference? Nowadays, a French teen learns that $0\in\Bbb N$ and $0\not\in\Bbb N^*$ \[In the 1970's the formalism was even more present, at times to a questionable degree. As a 13yo I had to learn the definition of a vector (as in Euclidean plane geometry) as: _an equivalence class of the [equipollence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipollence_(geometry)) relation_. Which at the time did not make sense to anyone in the class\].

Comment: Afaik the definition without $0$ is taught in school in Germany. Also most mathematicians here use this definition afaict. It's mainly computer scientists who include the $0$. I know that this is different in other countries. It leads to all kinds of misunderstandings. The German Wikipedia article has a whole section dedicated to this inconsistency.

Comment: @Maher: thanks for the info. Found an English reference, the entry on $\Bbb N$ [at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols#Symbols_based_on_Latin_letters).